# VS2010 - boolean setting being set incorrectly

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a maddening problem that I feel may be a gremlin that won't be slain.

In a C# application that I've moved from VS2005 to VS2010, I have a application setting that is a Boolean, set to default of False in the settings screen in the IDE.

However, when I fire up the program, even setting a breakpoint in void Main, this setting is set to True.  Nowhere do I set this to True in code, and the variable hasn't even been accessed before this breakpoint, which is even before I launch the main application form.

What's MORE, when I run this same project in VS2005, and set the breakpoint in the same exact place, it is False, which is correct.

I've restarted VS2010, tried setting the value manually, which of course works.  I even restarted my workstation, all to no avail.  I hate stuff like this...

Thanks.

Comment: When we upgraded from 2005 to 2010, some of the projects gained an app.config that was not there before, you may want to check if this is being included (and copied to the output directory) and that this file contains the bool you are looking for.

Comment: you should put that as an answer, not just a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I do NOT like answering my own stuff - try not to, but just stumbled across the solution.  As dumb as it sounds, I had to delete the setting in the IDE, and re-add it, after which it behaves properly.

I would love to hear someone familiar enough with the 'guts' of VS explain WHY this happened, but at any rate, that's what I had to do to fix it.